# Is there a way to determine start and end dates on Chartkick Line Chart?

Tags: ruby, chartkick

I want to create a Chartkick line chart where I'm able to determine (hardcoded) the start and end dates of my chart. The chart will be a time series of a model.

The thing is that I want the left and right ends of the x-axis to be **always** showing independently of what data points I have plotted on the chart. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably not understanding the question, but:

`<%= line_chart data, xmin: "123", xmax: "456" %>`

And two years later, it won't be much help.

Comment: Don't even remember what I was doing hehe, but thanks tho